# Distribution question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

How do we know these things about Zn that I circled in pink in this answer in the picture below? (In the above picture is the question and in the bottom is the answer). For instance how do we know that Zn ->y? And why do we say that since Zn>=0,we have P(Zn) =1? Basically, could someone please explain this answer in simpler terms? Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the $X_k$ take values of either $0$ or $1$. So the smallest possible value of $Z_n$ happens when $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n = 0$, which gives $Z_n \geq 2 \sum \frac{0}{3^k} = 0$. And the largest possible value of $Z_n$ happens when $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_n = 1$, so $Z_n \leq 2 \sum \frac{1}{3^k} \leq 1$. Then if $0 \leq Z_n \leq 1$ is always true, $P(Z_n \in [0, 1]) = 1$.

The last part, saying $Z_n \rightarrow Y$, is because $Y$ was defined as the limit of the $Z_n$, and if all of the $Z_n$ are bounded by $[0, 1]$ then $Y$ must also be bound in the same interval.